# Cart Data are not saved

Tags: php, forms, action, cart

I am working on a project with PHP.I have a product page and a cart page.
The product page has a couple of checkboxes and they are submitted with $_POST method in the cart.I get the right result (prints out the cart items) , but when i refresh the page, the cart gets empty.Why is this happening? I can't figure it out.

```
 <body>

            <div>   

            <h2>Your Shopping Cart So far: </h2>
                    <?php
                        if(!empty($_POST['addCart'])) {
                            foreach($_POST['addCart'] as $check) {
                                    $items=array($_POST['addCart']);

                                    echo $check; 
                                    print("<br>");                      
                            }
                        }   


                        ?>
            </div>      

</body>

 **products.php**
        <body>
            <?php
            $my_array=array('Scarf','Hat','Pocket','Gun');
            $_SESSION['items']=$my_array;
            ?>

                <form action="lab3.php?p=cart" method="post" >
                  <ul>
                     <li>
                          <p><?php 
                          echo $_SESSION['items'][0];
                          ?></p>
                         <input type="checkbox" name="addCart[]" value="<?php                                                                

                          echo  $_SESSION['items'][0] ?>">
                     </li>  
                     <li>
                     <p><?php 
                         echo $_SESSION['items'][1];
                     ?></p>
                         <input type="checkbox" name="addCart[]" value="<?php 
                          echo $_SESSION['items'][1] ?>">
                     </li>      
                     <li>
                     <p><?php 
                         echo $_SESSION['items'][2];
                     ?></p>
                         <input type="checkbox" name="addCart[]" value="<?php 

                         echo $_SESSION['items'][2] ?>">
                     </li>
                     <li>
                     <p><?php 
                         echo $_SESSION['items'][3];
                     ?></p>
                         <input type="checkbox" name="addCart[]" value="<?php 

                          echo $_SESSION['items'][3] ?>">
                     </li>  
                    </ul>
                        <input type="submit" value="Add to Cart">
             </form>
            </body>
```

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Still same problem!

Comment: @AniketSahrawat I tried a few different ways to access that.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat I want to send the post data in that section.Why use the main page (lab3.php) ?

Answer (score 0):

I dont see anywhere, where you telling the application that you will be using sessions
Which is :

```
<?PHP session_start()?>
```

Just put this on top of both pages to tell the application that you will be using sessions

Comment: Sessions are already started in the main program, these are just parts of it.

Comment: session_start() should be  written in every page that uses sessions,